# I'm trying to get more than 6 keys to register on windows

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard

I have written the following code, it requires June 2010 directX to run it:

https://github.com/jimmyt1988/MultipleKeys

The problem is that if you press 1 through to 8 all down at once, it only picks up 6 keys. Is there a way around this? I am of course using an array of keys to keep track of what is being held down.

context is that Rayman Legends a new game is multiplayer, you tend to want to play on one keyboard or 2 keyboards plugged in, but what happens is as you bash keys you cancel each others moves out, so I would like to try and prove to them it can be overcome, but at the moment it's not looking promising.

Comment: This is a hardware issue. 6 is pretty good for most keyboards.

Comment: What about if I plug two keyboards in, do I need to interface two keyboards in some special way? #complex? P.S I have a Razer Black widow, it's like 100 quid keyboard, I'm quite surprised this is its limit.

Comment: You can buy the [StackOverflow keyboard](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2013/08/the-code-keyboard.html)...

Comment: Some PS2 keyboards support full N-key rollover, but USB has a limit of 6.

Comment: That's insane, when I plug my second keyboard in, it does not even work more than 6 keys. grr. I forsee some intense research coming on. freaking hell.

Comment: Logitech G710+, for example, uses TWO USB ports to get around this (26-key rollover!)

Comment: What about windows 8, that can take 10 multi touch inputs, is it a limitation of usb or just keyboards themselves? can anyone think of tricks around this issue;

Comment: It's part of the USB protocol for keyboards.  http://blog.controlspace.org/2010/08/n-key-rollover-what-it-is-and-how-to.html

Comment: @RetiredNinja to add to that, the limitation comes from the predefined HID USB keyboard profile protocol for boot time (see page 60 http://www.usb.org/developers/devclass_docs/HID1_11.pdf). This protocol has the most compatibility among devices (all PC OSs and many non-PC devices too). Most people don't need to have more simultaneous key presses, so most manufacturers don't equip the hardware with the capability to speak another protocol when prompted by their driver to circumvent this limitation but it would be possible.

Comment: @PeterT It would be cool if they did allow for a different protocol if available.  Til then there's always the PS/2 adapter and hope that motherboard manufacturers don't start removing the PS/2 ports.

Comment: On PS/2 keyboard you could go up to 8 simultaneous keys. But not on every key combination. It's difficult to have 8 continuous key work but having a,s,d then k,l,m then keypad 4,5,6 is often possible

Comment: I am wondering whether there would be a way to trick Windows into thinking there was a second USB keyboard plugged in on the 6th key press, so that it takes input from the second keyboard (which is actually just the current keyboard)..?

Comment: The Shift, Ctrl, Alt and Win keys on both sides of the keyboard (i.e. 8 keys total) don't count towards the limit of 6.  If both players get, say, a shift key, a control key and two others then you won't hit the USB protocol limit.  But note that many keyboards have a limit on the number of keys that they can simultaneously handle which is independent of the USB protocol limit.

Comment: I'll test that out on my program